# Implementation of comet chat sdk in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, sdk, cometchat

I have been trying to implement come chat into my app and it has been really difficult for some days now. I finally initialized it but it gives me an error when i try to implement it when a user logs in. Here is my code below

```
private fun logChat() {
    val UID: String? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid // Replace with the UID of the user to login
    val AUTH_KEY = "a7cd1825ba915ecc3732c8896ae7f2f4fa9d4b5d" // Replace with your App Auth Key
    CometChat.login(UID.toString(), AUTH_KEY, object : CometChat.CallbackListener<User?>() {
        override fun onSuccess(user: User?) {

        }

        override fun onError(e: CometChatException) {

        }
    })
}
```

It gives the following error: `Type mismatch. Required: CometChat.CallbackListener<User!> Found:`

But it doesnt indicate what was found. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Add import com.cometchat.pro.models.User.
Nice to help you

Answer (score 0):

change your code to like this

```
    private fun logChat() {
    val UID: String? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid // Replace with the UID of the user to login
    val AUTH_KEY = "a7cd1825ba915ecc3732c8896ae7f2f4fa9d4b5d" // Replace with your App Auth Key
    CometChat.login(UID.toString(), AUTH_KEY, object : CometChat.CallbackListener<User>() {
        override fun onSuccess(user: User) {

        }

        override fun onError(e: CometChatException) {

        }
    })
}
```

sdk source code define method parameter NonNull

```
public static void login(@androidx.annotation.NonNull java.lang.String s, @androidx.annotation.NonNull java.lang.String s1, @androidx.annotation.NonNull com.cometchat.pro.core.CometChat.CallbackListener<com.cometchat.pro.models.User> callbackListener) { /* compiled code */ }
```